# Test case for statechangestart

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, state, karma-jasmine

Can anyone assist me with the below scenario, how to achieve this using karma angular. $stateChangeSuccess is easy without any callback function. But finding difficult for stateChangeStart.

```
        $scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
            if (fromState.name.match('test.abc') && ($scope.validate())) {
                event.preventDefault();                    
            }
        });
```

Trying something like below, but i am not sure, i am in the right path

```
    var fromState = {name: 'test.abc'};
    var toState = {name: 'test.xyz'};

    scope.$on('$stateChangeStart');

    expect(scope.$on).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(fromState.name)toBe('test.abc');
       /* expect event prevent default? */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is inside controller, then you can simply spyOn($scope, '$on');

Here is simple example:

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('Example', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$on('event', (event, args) => {
      $scope.args = args;
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  });

describe('Example Controller', () => {
  let Example;
  let $scope;
  
  beforeEach(module('app'));
  
  beforeEach(inject(($controller, $rootScope) => {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    spyOn($scope, '$on');
    $scope.$on.and.callThrough();
    
    Example = $controller('Example', {
      $scope
    });
  }));
  
  it('sets args on $scope when event is fired', () => {
    const args = 'args';
    
    $scope.$emit('event', args);
    
    expect($scope.args).toBe('args');
  });
  
  it('event callback stops propagation', () => {
    const [, callback] = $scope.$on.calls.argsFor(0);
    const event = jasmine.createSpyObj('event', ['stopPropagation']);
    
    callback(event);
    
    expect(event.stopPropagation).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine-html.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/boot.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular-mocks.js'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.css'>
```

Comment: Do i need to pass fromState, toState args in it?

Comment: @Hansie you can pass whatever you wish to callback. When extracted like in example above it is just a normal function. No different than any other. In your particular case, you have to pass this fromState, because otherwise fromState.name.match('test.abc') would throw exception.

Comment: thank you, sorry for last dumb question. can that args be an array? i need to pass `event, toState, toParams, fromState`. how exactly shud i pass this all? either by array? And event should be spyed or to be passed by creating an external mock using `var event = scope.$broadcast('click');` plz clarrify

Comment: @Hansie Broadcast or emit, send event true angular scope event mechanism, so event is created for you and it is hard to check if some function was called on it like ``preventDefault`` in your case. Co it is better to extract callback passed to $on, like I did in example above. Then you can just  ``callback(event, toState, toParams, fromState)``